# Does metal oxidize (faster) in dirt?

Tags: metal

I had an interesting event occur recently: I stuck a screwdriver in a potted plant, for it is the only way that I am able to unlock a certain door. It was left in there for about a month before I needed it again, and, when I took it out, it had what I thought to be rust. I am doubting my original assumption.

I know for a fact that it is *not* dirt itself, as I vigorously attempted to clean it with suds (though I'm not entirely sure whether or not that was the best approach...).

## Question

Does iron `a)` oxidize in dirt and `b)` if a), does it oxidize *faster* in dirt?

Comment: Was the dirt wet or moist?

Comment: @Michael I'm not entirely sure, though I'd assume moist, for I did water the plant a bit.

Comment: Moisture greatly increases the rate of corrosion. See theo's answer.

Comment: What is "dirt" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iron can corrode faster in soil than in air, particularly if partly immersed in the soil. Moisture and electrolyte are retained in the soil, making it a good anode. Also, microbes in the soil can accelerate corrosion.

Comment: Unless it is under cathodic protection like a pipeline.